# UPDATE запрос в MS Access - ошибка: "В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос"

Tags: sql, ms-access

В MS Access T-SQL

```
UPDATE Grid AS t1
INNER JOIN Im_SAPUsers AS t2
ON t1.[Имя пользователя] = t2.[sapuserid]
SET t1.[УчастокУчета] =t2.[Department];
```

Подскажите пжл, как так переписать запрос, чтобы MS Access не выдавал ошибку: "В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос"

```
UPDATE Grid AS t1
SET t1.[УчастокУчета] =
(SELECT [Department] FROM Im_SAPUsers AS t2 WHERE t1.[Имя пользователя] = t2.[sapuserid]);
```

Выдает ту же ошибку:

> В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос

Comment: Что такое `Grid` - таблица или вью?

Comment: Примечание: в Access не используется T-SQL

Comment: [Совместимость Access со сторонними источниками данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Совместимость_Access_со_сторонними_источниками_данных). Что является источником данных?

Comment: Grid - таблица в эксэсе, Im_SAPUsers - линкованная таблица в эксесе

Comment: Как минимум `t2.[sapuserid]` должен быть уникальным. В структуре. Иначе результат будет невменяемый...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE Grid AS t1
INNER JOIN Im_SAPUsers AS t2
ON t1.[Имя пользователя] = t2.[sapuserid]
SET t1.[УчастокУчета] = [t2]![Department];
```